# Kafka cluster configuration in multiple nodes

Tags: apache-kafka, cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper

I need to configure a Kafka cluster on different machines but it does not work, when I start producer and consumer the following errors are displayed:

### Producer Error Output

[image]

### Consumer Error Output

[image]

Can you help me please.

Comment: You are a new contributor. Welcome to Stackoverflow. The quality of the question can be improved by specifying what are you trying to do, what you have done so far, what tutorial are you following, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get started, I would recommend to read https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart. BTW, in your case; you haven't started Kafka yet.

You should start services in following order:

- zookeeper
- Kafka
- producer
- consumer

Comment: Thank you for your reponce, I already consult the official website. zookeeper and kafka are already launched and the topic is created but the producer and the consumer does not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788697/leader-not-available-kafka-in-console-producer