Problem with Kafka customer integration test with TestContainer
I have a problem while testing the integration of a Kafka consumer with kafkaContainer.
In practice, when I send the message with the template, the consumer is not invoked.
Can you help me?
Here is some code:
Consumer:
@Component
@Slf4j
public class BCDConsumer {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private BCDProducerService bluetoothCountingDataProducer;
    private TenantMapper tenantMapper;
    private ConsumerWithErrorManagement consumerWithErrorManagement;

    private Timer timer = Metrics.timer("maas.kafka.consumer", "type", "BluetoothCountingDataBulk");

    @Autowired
    public BCDConsumer(
            ObjectMapper objectMapper,
            BCDProducerService bluetoothCountingDataProducer,
            TenantMapper tenantMapper,
            ConsumerWithErrorManagement consumerWithErrorManagement) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.bluetoothCountingDataProducer = bluetoothCountingDataProducer;
        this.tenantMapper = tenantMapper;
        this.consumerWithErrorManagement = consumerWithErrorManagement;
    }

    @KafkaListener(
            topics = "${kafka.bluetooth.counting.data.bulk.topic}",
            containerFactory = "dataKafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void consumerBCDTopic(
            String message, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC) String topic) {
        timer.record(() -> performWithErrorManagement(topic, message));
    }

    private void performWithErrorManagement(String topic, String message) {
        consumerWithErrorManagement.consumeMessage(topic, message, "", () -> perform(message));
    }

    private void perform(String message) throws ValidationException {
        log.debug("consumerBCDTopic - consumer messages on 'BluetoothCountingData' topic");

        List<BluetoothCountingDataDTO> bluetoothCountingDataList;
        try {
            bluetoothCountingDataList = objectMapper.readValue(message, new TypeReference<>() {});
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error(
                    "Fatal Error during conversion of JSON String to TypeReference. No managed"
                            + " clean state",
                    e);
            throw new BusinessException(e);
        }
        for (BluetoothCountingDataDTO bluetoothCountingData : bluetoothCountingDataList) {
            for (DeviceDTO device : bluetoothCountingData.getDeviceDTOS()) {
                BusinessObjectWrapper<BluetoothCountingData> wrapper =
                        BCDBusinessFactory.createBCDBusiness(
                                bluetoothCountingData,
                                device,
                                tenantMapper.getTenantId(bluetoothCountingData.getOperator()));
                this.bluetoothCountingDataProducer.publishOnKafkaOfficialTopic(wrapper);
            }
        }
    }
}

Service (BCDProducerService):
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class BCDProducerService
        implements ProducerService<
                BluetoothCountingDataDTO, BusinessObjectWrapper<BluetoothCountingData>> {

    private final Timer bulkTimer =
            Metrics.timer("maas.kafka.producer", "topic", "bluetooth.counting.data.bulk.topic");
    private final Timer timer =
            Metrics.timer("maas.kafka.producer", "topic", "bluetooth.counting.data.topic");

    @Value("${kafka.bluetooth.counting.data.bulk.topic}")
    private final String internalTopicName;

    @Value("${kafka.bluetooth.counting.data.topic}")
    private final String topicName;

    private final KafkaProducer kafkaProducer;

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> publishListOnKafkaBulkTopic(
            List<BluetoothCountingDataDTO> payload) {
        log.debug(
                "publish list of {} elements into 'BluetoothCountingData' bulk topic",
                payload.size());
        bulkTimer.record(
                () -> {
                    try {
                        return this.kafkaProducer.publish(internalTopicName, payload);
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        throw new ProducerServiceException(e);
                    }
                });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void publishOnKafkaOfficialTopic(BusinessObjectWrapper<BluetoothCountingData> payload) {
        log.debug("publish an element on 'BluetoothCountingData' topic - element: {}", payload);

        timer.record(
                () -> {
                    try {
                        this.kafkaProducer.publish(topicName, payload);
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        throw new ProducerServiceException(e);
                    }
                });
    }
}

This is my integration test that doesn't work:
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest(classes = BCDConsumer.class)
@Import(ExampleIntegrationTest.KafkaTestContainersConfiguration.class)
class ExampleIntegrationTest {

    @Container
    private static final KafkaContainer kafkaContainer =
            new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka"))
                    .withEnv("KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE", "true");

    @Autowired private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @MockBean private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean private TenantMapper tenantMapper;

    @MockBean private BCDProducerService producer;

    //@MockBean private KafkaProducer kafkaProducer;

    @MockBean private ConsumerWithErrorManagement consumerWithErrorManagement;

    @Autowired private BCDConsumer consumer;

    @Value("${kafka.bluetooth.counting.data.bulk.topic}")
    private String topic;

    //TEST

    @Value("${kafka.bluetooth.counting.data.bulk.topic}")
    private String internalTopicName;

    @Value("${kafka.bluetooth.counting.data.topic}")
    private String topicName;

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap.address}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Value("${consumer.data.group.id}")
    private String groupId;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.listener.concurrency}")
    private int concurrency;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setup() {
        kafkaContainer.start();
        System.setProperty("kafka.bootstrap.address", kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers());
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void stopContainers() {
        kafkaContainer.stop();
    }

    @Test
    void shouldSendTheMessage() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Topic:" + topic);
        System.out.println("Internal topic:" + internalTopicName);
        System.out.println("Topic name:" + topicName);
        System.out.println("Address:" + bootstrapAddress);
        System.out.println("GroupId:" + groupId);
        System.out.println("Concurrency:" + concurrency);

        final BluetoothCountingDataDTO bluetoothData = createBluetoothCountingDataDTO();
        final String message = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(List.of(bluetoothData));

        final CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message);
        System.out.println(future);
        future.get();
        System.out.println(future);
        //kafkaTemplate.flush();

        Thread.sleep(8000);

        verify(producer, times(1)).publishOnKafkaOfficialTopic(any());
    }

    private BluetoothCountingDataDTO createBluetoothCountingDataDTO() {
        BluetoothCountingDataDTO dto = new BluetoothCountingDataDTO();
        dto.setType(1);
        dto.setTripId("trip");
        dto.setOperator("AMT");
        dto.setSequenceNumber(14L);
        dto.setDiagnosticStatus(0);
        dto.setVehicleId("vehicle");
        dto.setSourceSystemId("ss_id");
        dto.setParentVehicleId("parent");
        dto.setDeviceDTOS(createDeviceDtoList());
        dto.setSysTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        dto.setMessageId("addebf16-dcc3-40e8-bc11-a8ed2f01cc55");
        return dto;
    }

    private List<DeviceDTO> createDeviceDtoList() {
        DeviceDTO device = new DeviceDTO();
        device.setStatus(1);
        device.setLatitude(14d);
        device.setLongitude(47.23d);
        device.setStopId("stop_id");
        device.setDeviceId("dev_id");
        device.setBleTs(System.currentTimeMillis());
        return Collections.singletonList(device);
    }


    @TestConfiguration
    static class KafkaTestContainersConfiguration {

        @Bean
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory =
                    new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
            factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory() {
            return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
        }

        @Bean
        public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers());
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "acIngestionData");
            //props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, "PLAINTEXT");
            return props;
        }

        @Bean
        public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
            Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
            configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers());
            configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
            configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
            return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
        }

        @Bean
        public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> template = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
            template.setDefaultTopic("bluetoothCountingDataBulk");
            return template;
        }

        @Bean
        public NewTopic topic() {
            System.out.println("Sto cercando di creare il topic");
            return new NewTopic("bluetoothCountingDataBulk", 1, (short) 1);
        }

        /*
         @Bean
         @Primary
         public NewTopic newTopic() {
             System.out.println("Sto cercando di creare il topic");
             return TopicBuilder.name(topic)
                     .compact()
                     .build();
         }
         */
    }

}

This is the test/application.properties
########################################
# SPRING WEB
########################################
server.servlet.contextPath=/ac-ingestion
spring.application.name=ac-ingestion
application.instance.id=${random.uuid}

##########################
# ControllerAdvise
##########################
sdk.controller.advise.enable=true

########################################
# KAFKA
########################################
kafka.bootstrap.address=http://localhost:9092
kafka.consumer.threadModel.core.pool.size=1
kafka.consumer.threadModel.max.pool.size=0
kafka.consumer.threadModel.keepAliveSeconds=1
kafka.consumer.threadModel.threadNamePrefix=kafka-cons
kafka.stream.prefix=kafka
kafka.concurrency.thread=2

consumer.data.group.id=acIngestionData
spring.kafka.listener.concurrency=2

########################################
# KAFKA TOPICS
########################################
kafka.seat.counting.data.aggregate.topic=seatCountingDataAggregate
kafka.seat.counting.data.aggregate.bulk.topic=seatCountingDataAggregateBulk
kafka.people.counting.data.topic=peopleCountingData
kafka.carriage.counting.data.topic=carriageFlowOrCount
kafka.carriage.weight.data.topic=carriageWeight
kafka.carriage.position.data.topic=carriagePosition
kafka.vehicle.flow.data.topic=vehicleFlow
kafka.people.counting.data.bulk.topic=peopleCountingDataBulk
kafka.carriage.counting.data.bulk.topic=carriageFlowOrCountBulk
kafka.carriage.weight.data.bulk.topic=carriageWeightBulk
kafka.carriage.position.data.bulk.topic=carriagePositionBulk
kafka.bluetooth.counting.data.topic=bluetoothCountingDataTopic
kafka.bluetooth.counting.data.bulk.topic=bluetoothCountingDataBulk
kafka.position.topic=positionTopic
kafka.position.bulk.topic=positionBulk
kafka.station.congestion.topic=stationCongestion
kafka.station.congestion.bulk.topic=stationCongestionBulk
kafka.station.tracking.topic=stationTracking
kafka.station.tracking.bulk.topic=stationTrackingBulk
kafka.station.queues.topic=stationQueue
kafka.station.queues.bulk.topic=stationQueuesBulk
kafka.inter.carriage.counting.data.bulk.topic=intercarriageFlowOrCountBulk

########################################
# MQTT TOPICS
########################################
mqtt.station.congestion.topic=operators/amt/entitytype/STATION/congestion
mqtt.station.tracking.topic=operators/amt/entitytype/STATION/tracking
mqtt.station.queues.topic=operators/amt/entitytype/STATION/queues
mqtt.vehicle.congestion.topic=operators/amt/entitytype/VEHICLE/congestion
mqtt.vehicle.position.topic=operators/amt/entitytype/VEHICLE/position
mqtt.train.congestion.topic=operators/amt/entitytype/TRAIN/congestion
mqtt.train.intercarriage.topic=operators/amt/entitytype/TRAIN/intercarriage
mqtt.train.position.topic=operators/amt/entitytype/TRAIN/position
mqtt.bulk.topic=mqttBulk
mqtt.broker.address=tcp://broker.emqx.io:1883

#######################################
###MONITORING-CORE CLIENT
#######################################
http.monitoringcore.base.url=http://localhost:8081/monitoring-core

########################################
# ACTUATOR
########################################
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,metrics,prometheus,info
management.endpoint.health.show-details=never
management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
management.health.livenessState.enabled=true
management.health.readinessState.enabled=true

########################################
# LOG LEVELS
########################################
logging.level.com.hitachirail.maas=INFO
logging.pattern.console=-%clr(%clr(${application.instance.id}) %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}}

########################################
# KAFKA LOG LEVEL
########################################
logging.level.org.apache.kafka=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.kafka=INFO

########################################
# JACKSON
########################################
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false

################################
# SDK library
#################################
consumer.with.error.management.enabled=true


##############################
input.validity.days=7

################################
# MQTT
#################################
mqtt.enabled = true

######################
# SECURITY-FRAMEWORK #
######################
security.framework.jwt.validation = false
security.framework.jwt.header = Authorization
security.framework.jwt.extra.header = X-USERINFO

Test output:
Topic:bluetoothCountingDataBulk
Internal topic:bluetoothCountingDataBulk
Topic name:bluetoothCountingDataTopic
Address:PLAINTEXT://localhost:63529
GroupId:acIngestionData
Concurrency:2
11:04:50.042 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  INFO ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = -1
    auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [PLAINTEXT://localhost:63529]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = producer-1
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = true
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.adaptive.partitioning.enable = true
    partitioner.availability.timeout.ms = 0
    partitioner.class = null
    partitioner.ignore.keys = false
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

11:04:50.129 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
11:04:50.203 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  INFO Kafka version: 3.4.1
11:04:50.203 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  INFO Kafka commitId: 8a516edc2755df89
11:04:50.203 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  INFO Kafka startTimeMs: 1717319090203
11:04:50.581 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {bluetoothCountingDataBulk=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
11:04:50.583 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: SStqQtL4TK-6DpN4NqMJrw
11:04:50.698 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] ProducerId set to 0 with epoch 0
11:04:50.703 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 5 : {bluetoothCountingDataBulk=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
11:04:50.812 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition bluetoothCountingDataBulk-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to 78gvCLt6RkahgisJjaw97w
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@54d2f5d3[Not completed]
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@54d2f5d3[Completed normally]


Wanted but not invoked:
com.hitachirail.maas.acingestion.streaming.service.BCDProducerService#0 bean.publishOnKafkaOfficialTopic(
    <any>
);
-> at com.hitachirail.maas.acingestion.streaming.service.BCDProducerService.publishOnKafkaOfficialTopic(BCDProducerService.java:58)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

Wanted but not invoked:
com.hitachirail.maas.acingestion.streaming.service.BCDProducerService#0 bean.publishOnKafkaOfficialTopic(
    <any>
);
-> at com.hitachirail.maas.acingestion.streaming.service.BCDProducerService.publishOnKafkaOfficialTopic(BCDProducerService.java:58)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

    at com.hitachirail.maas.acingestion.streaming.service.BCDProducerService.publishOnKafkaOfficialTopic(BCDProducerService.java:58)
    at com.hitachirail.maas.acingestion.streaming.consumer.ExampleIntegrationTest.shouldSendTheMessage(ExampleIntegrationTest.java:141)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)

What am I doing wrong?
I've tried so many ways, but unfortunately, the consumer is never invoked. The message in Kafka seems to be sent correctly.

Is the property "kafka.bluetooth.counting.data.bulk.topic" set to "BluetoothCountingDataBulk" somewhere in your test configuration? In the integration test you show, you hardcode the topic to "BluetoothCountingDataBulk" but the consumer code listens to a topic based on the property "kafka.bluetooth.counting.data.bulk.topic". Check that property has a value when running your test.

Hi man, thanks for the answer.
Yes, there is the value.
I have just updated the question with test/application.properties.

I confirm that topicName is correctly detected from properties.

Added test output: you can see this error:
Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {bluetoothCountingDataBulk=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}

I found a similar error in stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788697/leader-not-available-kafka-in-console-producer. Maybe you could try configuring the test container with an environment variable.

I’m using testcontainer. Have I a server.properties too?

You do not have a server. properties but you can configure your broker by providing environment variables as you do now "withEnv("KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE", "true")". That has the same effect as having a server. Properties.

A found also an example of an integration test for Kafka https://testcontainers.com/guides/testing-spring-boot-kafka-listener-using-testcontainers/#_write_test_for_kafka_listener. My feeling is that your configuration KafkaTestContainersConfiguration is somehow setting something wrong. Check the example in the tutorial and see if you can simplify your test accordingly.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

First of all take a look on these lines in your log:
11:04:50.581 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {bluetoothCountingDataBulk=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
11:04:50.583 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: SStqQtL4TK-6DpN4NqMJrw
11:04:50.698 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] ProducerId set to 0 with epoch 0
11:04:50.703 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 5 : {bluetoothCountingDataBulk=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}
11:04:50.812 trace_id= span_id= trace_flags=  INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition bluetoothCountingDataBulk-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to 78gvCLt6RkahgisJjaw97w

You probably might want to set topicId into your producer config explicitly. But my guess you don't really need to create producer at all if you want to test consumer, so I think you can remove it completely.
Also set acks property to all to your producer if you want to leave it to be sure the message is delivered.
Also return topic creation process and create it with single partition to make sure you produce and consumer from the same one.
Secondly, you might need to set offset reset to earliest in your consumer:
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
   Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
   props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
   ....
   return props;
}

Otherwise, some messages might be lost, for instance, when test context was reset.
Third thing, use more guaranteed synchronisation between test code and listener code than just sleep. I can suggest you to @SpyBean your listener and add CountDownLatch:
In test:
@SpyBean
private BCDConsumer consumer;

...

@Test
void shouldSendTheMessage() throws Exception {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    doAnswer(inv -> {
        try {
            return inv.callRealMethod();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            latch.countDown();
        }
        }).when(consumer).consumerBCDTopic(nullable(String.class), nullable(String.class));
    .....

    kafkaTemplate.send(topic, message).join()
    
    assertTrue(latch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

    verify(producer, times(1)).publishOnKafkaOfficialTopic(any());
}

Last thing, you use @MockBean, @SpyBean annotations, using them will make Spring context dirty and it will be reset after each test method, and each time it will create new instance of your kafka listener BCDConsumer.
But you start your kafka container once for all methods in the test class, which means that each time after context is being reset, new consumer will be registered into existing topic and partition, kafka will be trying to resolve that conflict and it might affect your test as well, i.e. kafka might just won't register new one to the topic.
That's not you case just because you have only one test method at that moment, but be aware of that.
You can optimize that by overriding your beans with mocks in test configuation, but not forget to reset them before/after each test.
