# How to subscribe to the topic in apache kafka from the java application?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

This is the consumer for the apache kafka and it is not getting the messages from the topic "test"

```
package com.kafka;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

public class ConsumerTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.put("bootstrap.servers", "172.17.210.45:9092");
     props.put("zookeeper.connect", "172.17.210.45:2181");
     props.put("group.id", "test-consumer-group");
     props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
     props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
     props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
     props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
     props.put("key.deserializer",  "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
     props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

     KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
     System.out.println("properties loaded");
     kafkaConsumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("test"));

     while (true) {
         ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(100);
         for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records) {
           System.out.printf("offset = %d, value = %s", record.offset(), record.value());
           System.out.println();
         }
     }

  }
}
```

In this result am not getting any messages from the apache kafka.

```
     log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger                                                                                                                (org.apach  e.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig).
     log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
properties loaded
```

Comment: had you found what's wrong?

Comment: Are you producing messages while the consumer is running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a Topic in Kafka through Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036923/how-to-create-a-topic-in-kafka-through-java)

Comment: Please could you tell me which of my suggestions was right? Just curious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems correct. I suggest to control if ip `172.17.210.45` is reachable.

```
ping 172.17.210.45
```

and

```
telnet 172.17.210.45 9092
telnet 172.17.210.45 2181
```

Check the existing topics on the server

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper 172.17.210.45:2181
```

Then you could try to move your consumer to the beginning (this line has to be added after `kafkaConsumer.subscribe`:

```
kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning(Collections.emptyList());
```

At last I suggest to add few `System.out.println(records.size)` lines in the infinite loop, after `kafkaConsumer.poll(100)`. Just to see if hangs waiting for a record or what else.

**UPDATE**

If you have one or more group.id in the producer part, you should use one of them in the consumer part.

Comment: @freedev...If i add kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning(Collections.emptyList()); It is throwing the error..

Comment: Here am getting the list of topics, but am not getting the messages for the specific topic...

Comment: If you are reading from the topic "test" I assume that the topic exist. I also suggest to be sure to use same group id used by the producer part.