# Kafka 1.0.0 admin client cannot create topic with EOFException

Tags: scala, apache-kafka

Using the 1.0.0 Kafka admin client I wish to programmatically create a topic on the broker. I happen to be using Scala. I've tried using the following code to either create a topic on the Kafka broker or simply to list the available topics

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.{AdminClient, ListTopicsOptions, NewTopic}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val zkServer = "localhost:2181"
val topic = "test1"

val zookeeperConnect = zkServer
val sessionTimeoutMs = 10 * 1000
val connectionTimeoutMs = 8 * 1000


val partitions = 1
val replication:Short = 1
val topicConfig = new Properties() // add per-topic configurations settings here

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig
val config = new Properties
config.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, zkServer)
val admin = AdminClient.create(config)

val existing = admin.listTopics(new ListTopicsOptions().timeoutMs(500).listInternal(true))
val nms = existing.names()
nms.get().asScala.foreach(nm => println(nm)) // nms.get() fails

val newTopic = new NewTopic(topic, partitions, replication)
newTopic.configs(Map[String,String]().asJava)
val ret = admin.createTopics(List(newTopic).asJavaCollection)
ret.all().get() // Also fails
admin.close()
```

With either command, the ZooKeeper (3.4.10) side throws an EOFException and closes the connection. Debugging the ZooKeeper side itself, it seems it is unable to deserialize the message that the admin client is sending (it runs out of bytes it is trying to read)

Anyone able to make the 1.0.0 Kafka admin client work for creating or listing topics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AdminClient directly connects to Kafka and does not need access to Zookeeper.

You need to set `AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG` to point to your Kafka brokers (for example `localhost:9092`) instead of Zookeeper.

Comment: Many thanks! This is quite a gotcha compared to examples in 0.9/0.10 such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036923/how-to-create-a-topic-in-kafka-through-java where the APIs required you to connect to Zookeeper rather than Kafka