# Creating kafka topics with Java doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to create Kafka topics using Java. But I get a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_SSL_PRINCIPAL_MAPPING_RULES` and I can't fix it.

My goal is to create a topic so that when I run my Kafka server to display my topics using this command `bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`, I can actually see my topic in the list.

(the command is from Kafka's official website https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart)

I looked up to this problem [How to create a Topic in Kafka through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036923/how-to-create-a-topic-in-kafka-through-java) which actually inspired my code, but not only it doesn't really help, but it seems like it uses deprecated classes and methods.

I tried to use what I believed to be more recent classes such as `ZooKeeperClient`, `KafkaZkClient` and `AdminZkClient`, but from what I understand, the method `adminZkClient.createTopic(topic, noOfPartitions, noOfReplication, topicConfiguration, RackAwareMode.Disabled$.MODULE$);` is what brings the exception. I don't know what it is about that function that creates the exception, whether I forgot something from my `application.properties` file or something else.
Here's my code

```java
    import java.util.Properties;

    import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient;
    import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection;
    import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Time;
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;


    import kafka.admin.AdminUtils;
    import kafka.admin.RackAwareMode;
    import kafka.utils.ZkUtils;
    import kafka.zk.AdminZkClient;
    import kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient;
    import kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient;
    import kafka.utils.*;


    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableJpaAuditing
    public class ChatApplication {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public static void main(String[] args) {                
            try {
                String zookeeperHost = "127.0.0.1:2181"; 
                int sessionTimeOutInMs = 15 * 1000; 
                int connectionTimeOutInMs = 10 * 1000; 

                    ZooKeeperClient zooKeeperClient = new ZooKeeperClient(zookeeperHost, sessionTimeOutInMs, connectionTimeOutInMs, 2, Time.SYSTEM, "BytesInPerSec", "BytesOutPerSec");

                KafkaZkClient kafkaZkClient = new KafkaZkClient(zooKeeperClient, true, Time.SYSTEM);

                String topic = "superTopic";
                int noOfPartitions = 2;
                int noOfReplication = 1;
                Properties topicConfiguration = new Properties();

                AdminZkClient adminZkClient = new AdminZkClient(kafkaZkClient);

                adminZkClient.createTopic(topic, noOfPartitions, noOfReplication, topicConfiguration, RackAwareMode.Disabled$.MODULE$);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }




            //SpringApplication.run(ChatApplication.class, args);

    }
```

Here's the output I get :

```
    06:50:06.796 [main] INFO kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$ - Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean
    06:50:07.101 [main] INFO kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient - [ZooKeeperClient] Initializing a new session to 127.0.0.1:2181.
    06:50:07.116 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.13-2d71af4dbe22557fda74f9a9b4309b15a7487f03, built on 06/29/2018 00:39 GMT
    06:50:07.116 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:host.name=kunta
    06:50:07.116 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.version=11.0.3
    06:50:07.116 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    06:50:07.116 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
    06:50:07.116 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.class.path=/home/robscientist/STS-WORKSPACE/poc_chat/target/classes:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.11.2/log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.11.2/log4j-api-2.11.2.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.25/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.23/snakeyaml-1.23.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.8/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.8.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.9.8/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.8.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.16/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.16/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.16.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.16/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.16.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.14.Final/hibernate-validator-6.0.14.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.2.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.4.0/classmate-1.4.0.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/debezium/debezium-core/0.9.5.Final/debezium-core-0.9.5.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.9.8/jackson-core-2.9.8.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/debezium/debezium-core/0.9.5.Final/debezium-core-0.9.5.Final-tests.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-websocket/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-websocket-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-messaging/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-messaging-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-websocket/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-websocket-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.2/aspectjweaver-1.9.2.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/3.2.0/HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.3/javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.3.7.Final/hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/javax/persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.23.1-GA/javassist-3.23.1-GA.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.9.10/byte-buddy-1.9.10.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.5.Final/jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/dom4j/dom4j/2.1.1/dom4j-2.1.1.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.4.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/2.1.5.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.1.5.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-aspects-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.197/h2-1.4.197.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/webjars/stomp-websocket/2.3.3/stomp-websocket-2.3.3.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap-3.3.7.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/webjars/jquery/1.11.1/jquery-1.11.1.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/kafka/spring-kafka/2.2.4.RELEASE/spring-kafka-2.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/retry/spring-retry/1.2.4.RELEASE/spring-retry-1.2.4.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/2.0.1/kafka-clients-2.0.1.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/lz4/lz4-java/1.4.1/lz4-java-1.4.1.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.1.7.1/snappy-java-1.1.7.1.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/apache/kafka/kafka_2.12/2.2.0/kafka_2.12-2.2.0.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.8/jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.8/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.8.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/5.0.4/jopt-simple-5.0.4.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/com/yammer/metrics/metrics-core/2.2.0/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.12.8/scala-library-2.12.8.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.12.8/scala-reflect-2.12.8.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/com/typesafe/scala-logging/scala-logging_2.12/3.9.0/scala-logging_2.12-3.9.0.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/com/101tec/zkclient/0.11/zkclient-0.11.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.13/zookeeper-3.4.13.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.25/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/jline/jline/0.9.94/jline-0.9.94.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/apache/yetus/audience-annotations/0.5.0/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty/3.10.6.Final/netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/netty/reactor-netty/0.8.5.RELEASE/reactor-netty-0.8.5.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.33.Final/netty-codec-http-4.1.33.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.33.Final/netty-common-4.1.33.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-buffer/4.1.33.Final/netty-buffer-4.1.33.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport/4.1.33.Final/netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-resolver/4.1.33.Final/netty-resolver-4.1.33.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec/4.1.33.Final/netty-codec-4.1.33.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-http2/4.1.33.Final/netty-codec-http2-4.1.33.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler/4.1.33.Final/netty-handler-4.1.33.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-handler-proxy/4.1.33.Final/netty-handler-proxy-4.1.33.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-codec-socks/4.1.33.Final/netty-codec-socks-4.1.33.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.1.33.Final/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.33.Final-linux-x86_64.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-transport-native-unix-common/4.1.33.Final/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.33.Final.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/io/projectreactor/reactor-core/3.2.6.RELEASE/reactor-core-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/reactivestreams/reactive-streams/1.0.2/reactive-streams-1.0.2.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.2.5/postgresql-42.2.5.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.6/lombok-1.18.6.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-devtools/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:/home/robscientist/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar
    06:50:07.116 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
    06:50:07.116 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
    06:50:07.116 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
    06:50:07.116 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.name=Linux
    06:50:07.116 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
    06:50:07.117 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.version=4.15.0-50-generic
    06:50:07.117 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.name=robscientist
    06:50:07.117 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.home=/home/robscientist
    06:50:07.117 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.dir=/home/robscientist/STS-WORKSPACE/poc_chat
    06:50:07.118 [main] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=127.0.0.1:2181 sessionTimeout=15000 watcher=kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient$ZooKeeperClientWatcher$@5bda8e08
    06:50:07.120 [main] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - zookeeper.disableAutoWatchReset is false
    06:50:07.129 [main] DEBUG kafka.utils.KafkaScheduler - Initializing task scheduler.
    06:50:07.131 [main] INFO kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient - [ZooKeeperClient] Waiting until connected.
    06:50:07.138 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
    06:50:07.144 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
    06:50:07.145 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment request sent on localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
    06:50:07.403 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1000016739e0016, negotiated timeout = 15000
    06:50:07.409 [main-EventThread] DEBUG kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient - [ZooKeeperClient] Received event: WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
    06:50:07.415 [main] INFO kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient - [ZooKeeperClient] Connected.
    06:50:07.469 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Reading reply sessionid:0x1000016739e0016, packet:: clientPath:/brokers/ids serverPath:/brokers/ids finished:false header:: 1,12  replyHeader:: 1,237,0  request:: '/brokers/ids,F  response:: v{'0},s{5,5,1559484903664,1559484903664,0,5,0,0,0,1,191} 
    06:50:07.492 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Reading reply sessionid:0x1000016739e0016, packet:: clientPath:/brokers/ids/0 serverPath:/brokers/ids/0 finished:false header:: 2,4  replyHeader:: 2,237,0  request:: '/brokers/ids/0,F  response:: #7b226c697374656e65725f73656375726974795f70726f746f636f6c5f6d6170223a7b22504c41494e54455854223a22504c41494e54455854227d2c22656e64706f696e7473223a5b22504c41494e544558543a2f2f6b756e74613a39303932225d2c226a6d785f706f7274223a2d312c22686f7374223a226b756e7461222c2274696d657374616d70223a2231353539353332323533363131222c22706f7274223a393039322c2276657273696f6e223a347d,s{191,191,1559532253652,1559532253652,1,0,0,72057690466942976,180,0,191} 
    06:50:07.690 [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Reading reply sessionid:0x1000016739e0016, packet:: clientPath:/brokers/topics/superTopic serverPath:/brokers/topics/superTopic finished:false header:: 3,3  replyHeader:: 3,237,-101  request:: '/brokers/topics/superTopic,F  response::  
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_SSL_PRINCIPAL_MAPPING_RULES
    at kafka.server.Defaults$.<init>(KafkaConfig.scala:224)
    at kafka.server.Defaults$.<clinit>(KafkaConfig.scala)
    at kafka.log.Defaults$.<init>(LogConfig.scala:36)
    at kafka.log.Defaults$.<clinit>(LogConfig.scala)
    at kafka.log.LogConfig$.<init>(LogConfig.scala:219)
    at kafka.log.LogConfig$.<clinit>(LogConfig.scala)
    at kafka.zk.AdminZkClient.validateTopicCreate(AdminZkClient.scala:128)
    at kafka.zk.AdminZkClient.createTopicWithAssignment(AdminZkClient.scala:86)
    at kafka.zk.AdminZkClient.createTopic(AdminZkClient.scala:56)
    at com.predisurge.kafka.KafkaTopicCreator.createTopic(KafkaTopicCreator.java:41)
    at com.predisurge.ChatApplication.main(ChatApplication.java:32)
```

After running the command to display my topics, I don't see the one I want to add.

IDE : STS 4,
Kafka version : 2.2.0, 
ZK version : 3.5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure why you get this exception. Here's a solution that works for me, and just uses the KafkaAdminClient:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
public class TopicCreator {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    AdminClient kafkaAdminClient = KafkaAdminClient.create(properties);
    CreateTopicsResult result = kafkaAdminClient.createTopics(
            Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz").map(
                    name -> new NewTopic(name, 3, (short) 1)
            ).collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
    result.all().get();
  }

}
```

As the above code shows, for newer versions of Kafka you can create topics directly through Kafka. Does this help?

Comment: I just tried it and it works well. I displayed the list of topics I have, and I get ```foo, bar, baz``` among my topics. I have to admin that I didn't really know how to use the ```CreateTopicsResult``` and ```NewTopic```. Thank you so much !

Comment: Since you tagged the question with `spring-kafka`, I would also mention that you can simply add `NewTopic` `@Bean`s to the context, along with a `KafkaAdmin` `@Bean` and the framework will automatically provision the topic(s) for you during initialization. See [configuring topics](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#configuring-topics) in the reference manual. Spring Boot automatically configures an admin, so you only need the topic beans there.