# How to programmatically create a Topic in Kafka through spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I want to create multiple kafka Topics run time in my Spark Structured Streaming application. I found that there are various methods available in Java API. But I couldn't find any with Spark Structured Streaming.
Please let me know if there is any way available or I need to use java library

My apache Spark version is 2.4.4 and Kafka library dependency is spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12

Comment: if the topic does not exist, Spark create it automatically

Comment: Thanks, I really don't know

Comment: @Ahmed Does the broker need to have auto topic creation enabled? If not, how would Spark create a topic without setting replication or partition settings?

Comment: With auto creation off, I'd expect an exception. Same without proper credentials when using a secure Kafka cluster.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, Spark doesn't create topics.

You can use the same Java APIs you've found before initializing your SparkSession

spark-sql-kafka includes kafka-clients, so you have the AdminClient class available

[How to create a Topic in Kafka through Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036923/how-to-create-a-topic-in-kafka-through-java)

Comment: It does. And more specifically it's the kafka data source that does the writing part. Sorry. And please don't use `SparkContext` (Spark Core). It's `SparkSession` time (Spark SQL).

Comment: @Jacek Can you answer my comment above then?