# Can't import ZKStringSerializer$

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to create kafka topic in Java. I have a sample code from stackoverflow. But the problem is that I couldn't import ZKStringSerializer$ and ZkUtils. I have all maven dependencies. What is the reason? Her is the code:

```
import kafka.admin.AdminUtils;
import kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer$;
import kafka.utils.ZkUtils;
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient;
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection;


public class CreateKafkaTopic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZkClient zkClient = null;
        ZkUtils zkUtils = null;
        try {
            String zookeeperHosts = "192.168.20.1:2181"; // If multiple zookeeper then -> String zookeeperHosts = "192.168.20.1:2181,192.168.20.2:2181";
            int sessionTimeOutInMs = 15 * 1000; // 15 secs
            int connectionTimeOutInMs = 10 * 1000; // 10 secs

            zkClient = new ZkClient(zookeeperHosts, sessionTimeOutInMs, connectionTimeOutInMs, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
            zkUtils = new ZkUtils(zkClient, new ZkConnection(zookeeperHosts), false);

            String topicName = "testTopic";
            int noOfPartitions = 2;
            int noOfReplication = 3;
            Properties topicConfiguration = new Properties();

            AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtils, topicName, noOfPartitions, noOfReplication, topicConfiguration);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (zkClient != null) {
                zkClient.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.101tec/zkclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
    <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
    <version>0.11</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams-test-utils -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-streams-test-utils</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you copied from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27036923/how-to-create-a-topic-in-kafka-through-java)? If so, read the very top of that accepted answer.

Zookeeper is a deprecated method to create topics.

Use `AdminClient.createTopics` or a higher-level framework like dropwizard-kafka configuration or spring-kafka's `@Bean` to create topics

Also, use `kafka-clients` dependency, not the `kafka_[scala.version]` depdendency